# Assign result of execution an alias to variable in IPython

Tags: shell, alias, ipython

I am new to IPython and I am wondering how can I assign result of execution an alias to variable.

Let's say I'm using standard alias:

```
('ls', 'ls -F --color')
```

Now I want to do create variable with content of current directory using this alias:

```
content = <ls>
```

but I don't how to express that right hand side of the assignment is an alias and should be executed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`ls` is special cased in IPython you can do `foo =!ls` and have a list of file in cwd.

Comment: 'ls' was an example. I would like to use ANY alias that way. Moreover, alias is set to shorten instruction. To achieve same effect I should type foo = !ls -F --color.

Comment: `variable = !shell-command` will work in many cases, but you might not always get a list. If you need something specific you will have to write your own python function or IPython magic. You might need to uses subprocess.